# Laravel mssql db declare

Tags: database, laravel

This mssql **API Example** I need get to laravel query. Can somebody help me please? I don't have any experience with this query.

Table `API_CreateShopBasket` is for get item to basket.

```
DECLARE @return_value int
 EXEC @return_value = [API_CreateShopBasket] @CustomerID= 12 ,@CustomerWorkshopID= 12 ,@GroupID= 32 ,@ProductID= 34 ,@StorageCardID= -1 ,@OrderID= -1 ,@GroupCode= 'OP570' ,@ProductCode= 'A000000034' ,@ManufacturerCode= 'OP570' ,@SupplierCode= 'A000000034' ,@Brand= 'FILTRON' ,@Desription= 'Oil filter' ,@OrderedQuantity= 8 ,@PricePerPiece= 6.743 ,@PricePerPieceWithVAT= 8.29 ,@PurchasePricePerPiece= 5.348 ,@PurchasePricePerPieceWithVAT= 6.58 ,@TotalPrice= 53.94 ,@TotalPriceWithVAT= 66.32 ,@TotalPurchasePrice= 42.78 ,@TotalPurchasePriceWithVAT= 52.64 ,@DiscountInPercent= 20.7 ,@DiscountPrice= -11.16 ,@SurchargesPrice= 0 ,@SurchargePriceWithVAT= 0 ,@PricePerPieceInCurrency= 6.740 ,@PricePerPieceWithVATInCurrency= 8.290 ,@PurchasePricePerPieceInCurrency= 5.350 ,@PurchasePricePerPieceWithVATInCurrency= 6.580 ,@TotalPriceInCurrency= 53.920 ,@TotalPriceWithVATInCurrency= 66.320 ,@TotalPurchasePriceInCurrency= 42.800 ,@TotalPurchasePriceWithVATInCurrency= 52.640 ,@DiscountPriceInCurrency= -1.390 ,@SurchargesPriceInCurrency= 0 ,@SurchargesPriceWithVATInCurrency= 0 ,@CurrencyID= 16034 ,@ForeignCurrencyID= 16034 ,@Note= '',@VATRate= 23.00 ,@HistoryInfo= '' ,@ActionPrice= 0 ,@ChildPricePerPieceInCurrency= -1.000 ,@ChildPricePerPieceWithVATInCurrency= -1.000 ,@ChildPurchasePricePerPieceInCurrency= -1.000 ,@ChildPurchasePricePerPieceWithVATInCurrency= -1.000 ,@ChildDiscountInCurrency= -1.000
```